# Питон, деление на 0

Tags: python

Есть условие задачи:

> Обозначим через `ДЕЛ (n, m)` утверждение: «*натуральное число n делится без остатка на натуральное число m*».
>
> Для какого наименьшего натурального числа `А` формула `(ДЕЛ (X, A-21) И ДЕЛ (x, 40-A)) → ДЕЛ (x, 90)` тождественно истинна (то есть принимает значение 1 при любом натуральном значительном указании `х`)?

Я написал код, но не знаю почему мне выдаёт ошибку деления на 0:

```
def Del(x, n):
    return x % n == 0

def DelA(x, A):
    return (Del(x, A - 21) and Del(x, 40 - A) <= Del(x, 90))

for A in range(1, 1000):
    a = True
    for x in range(1, 1000):
        if DelA(x, A) == False:
            a = False
            break
    if a == True:
        print(A)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
return (Del(x, A - 21) and Del(x, 40 - A)
```

Если от 21 отнять 21, или от 40 отнять 40, то получится 0.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `Del` должна корректно обрабатывать `n==0` и возвращать `False` при любом значении `x`